# Turn List into number, increment the number, and then turn the number into a list

Tags: prolog

I have my head stuck in this exercise in prolog, I ve been trying to do it on my own but it just won't work. Example: ?-succesor([1,9,9],X) -> X = [2,0,0]. Had tried first to reverse the list and increment it with 1 and then do a if %10 = 0 the next element should be incremented too. Thing is that I m too used with programming syntax and I can't get my head wrapped around this.Any help would be appreciated.

I have done this so far, but the output is false.

```
%[1,9,9] -> 199 +1 -> 200;

numbers_atoms([],[]).
numbers_atoms([X|Y],[C|K]) :-
   atom_number(C, X),
   numbers_atoms(Y,K).

%([1,2,3],X)

digits_number(Digits, Number) :-
   numbers_atoms(Digits, Atoms),
   number_codes(Number, Atoms).

number_tolist( 0, [] ).
number_tolist(N,[A|As]) :-
   N1 is floor(N/10),
   A is N mod 10,
   number_tolist(N1, As).

addOne([X],[Y]):-
   digits_number(X,Y1), %[1,9,9] -> 199
   Y1 is Y1+1, % 199 -> 200
   number_tolist(Y1,[Y]), % 200 -> [2,0,0]
   !.
```

Comment: Did you post the same code twice?  If not, please identify the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem similarly to how you would solve it manually: traverse the list of digits until you reach the rightmost digit; increment that digit and compute the carry-on digit, which must be recursively propagated to the left. At the end, prepend the carry-on digit if it is equal to 1 (otherwise, ignore it).

```
% successor(+Input, -Output)

  successor([X0|Xs], L) :-
      successor(Xs, X0, C, Ys),
      (   C = 1                  % carry-on 
      ->  L = [C|Ys]
      ;   L = Ys ).

% helper predicate

  successor([], X, C, [Y]) :-
      Z is X + 1,
      Y is Z mod 10,
      C is Z div 10.             % carry-on 
  successor([X1|Xs], X0, C, [Y|Ys]) :-
      successor(Xs, X1, C0, Ys),
      Z is X0 + C0,
      Y is Z mod 10,
      C is Z div 10.             % carry-on
```

Examples:

```
?- successor([1,9,9], A).
A = [2, 0, 0].

?- successor([2,7],A), successor(A,B), successor(B,C), successor(C,D).
A = [2, 8],
B = [2, 9],
C = [3, 0],
D = [3, 1].

?- successor([7,9,9,8], A), successor(A, B).
A = [7, 9, 9, 9],
B = [8, 0, 0, 0].

?- successor([9,9,9,9], A), successor(A, B).
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
B = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1].
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version which doesn't use `is` and can work both ways:

```
successor(ListIn, ListOut) :-
    reverse(ListIn, ListInRev),
    ripple_inc(ListInRev, ListOutRev),
    reverse(ListOutRev, ListOut).

ripple_inc([], [1]).
ripple_inc([0|T], [1|T]).
ripple_inc([1|T], [2|T]).
ripple_inc([2|T], [3|T]).
ripple_inc([3|T], [4|T]).
ripple_inc([4|T], [5|T]).
ripple_inc([5|T], [6|T]).
ripple_inc([6|T], [7|T]).
ripple_inc([7|T], [8|T]).
ripple_inc([8|T], [9|T]).
ripple_inc([9|T], [0|Tnext]) :-
    ripple_inc(T, Tnext).
```

e.g.

```
?- successor([1,9,9], X).
X = [2, 0, 0]

?- successor([1,9,9], [2,0,0]).
true

?- successor(X, [2,0,0]).
X = [1, 9, 9]
```

although it's nicely deterministic when run 'forwards', it's annoying that if run 'backwards' it finds an answer, then leaves a choicepoint and then infinite loops if that choicepoint is retried. I think what causes that is starting from the higher number then `reverse(ListIn, ListInRev)` has nothing to work on and starts generating longer and longer lists both filled with empty variables and never ends.

I can constrain the input and output to be `same_length/2` but I can't think of a way to constrain them to be the same length or ListOut is one item longer ([9,9,9] -> [1,0,0,0]).

Comment: Look at my answer to see how to improve universal termination. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This answer tries to improve the [previous answer by @TessellatingHacker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625512/4609915), like so:

```
successor(ListIn, ListOut) :-
   no_longer_than(ListIn, ListOut),  % weaker than same_length/2
   reverse(ListIn, ListInRev),
   ripple_inc(ListInRev, ListOutRev),
   reverse(ListOutRev, ListOut).
```

The definition of `no_longer_than/2` follows. Note the similarity to `same_length/2`:

```
no_longer_than([],_).                % same_length([],[]).
no_longer_than([_|Xs],[_|Ys]) :-     % same_length([_|Xs],[_|Ys]) :- 
   no_longer_than(Xs,Ys).            %    same_length(Xs,Ys).
```

The following sample queries still succeed deterministically, as they did before:

```
?- successor([1,9,9], X).
X = [2,0,0].

?- successor([1,9,9], [2,0,0]).
true.
```

The "run backwards" use of `successor/2` now also terminates universally:

```
?- successor(X, [2,0,0]).
   X = [1,9,9]
;  false.
```